# I am getting following error while running Angular

Tags: angularjs

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Following is my code snippet

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Following is my code snippet

```
(function() {   
    angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            Colors: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        }   
    });

    angular.module('myApp').controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.list1 = {
            title: 'AngularJS - Drag Me'
        };

        $scope.list2 = {};   
    });

}());
```

Comment: You need to first create the module (2nd argument of module) just once before using it. i.e `angular.module('myApp',[])`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the getter syntax, not the setter syntax when attempting to first define `myApp`.

You need to create the `myApp` module before trying to attach a controller to it.  Note that it takes two parameters, a string name and an array of dependencies.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
```

Once your module is created, you can reference it via the getter syntax:

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope) {
```

Comment: @django You are welcome :).  If it works for you, although it's marked as a duplicate you can also accept my answer so that others who come across can use it as a solution as well.